# Bayesian update using probabilities from sampling method

Tags: probability, bayesian, independence

This is kind of a strange question and I am struggling a bit with how to approach this. I am quite new to Bayesian updating and Bayesian probabilities, so forgive me if I phrase this wrong.

My problem consists of a sampling methodology which provides either a positive or a negative and a confidence score which is a probability that it is correct. (i.e. it will say this is a positive sample and I am 95% confident). However, I am sampling it multiple times. So, the first time I sample it may be 95% confident, the second time I sample it may 94% confident, etc...

My initial assumption was that, the more times we sample, the more confident we can be. But from my initial looking at Bayesian updating, I'm not sure if this is the case? How do I go about this?

Thank you!